# Getting Eclipse to select words with key binding keyboard shortcuts

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I am trying to work in Eclipse on a thing with better support there. I want to make *CTRL+SHIFT+LEFT* select the word before the cursor and *CTRL+SHIFT+RIGHT* select the word after the cursor like in a normal text editor.

When I try set it up in **General -> Preferences -> Keys** by choosing *Next Word* and/or *Select Next Word* nothing happens when I try it afterwards. It seems broken.

Is there a fix or is this a bug?

Comment: *Ctrl+Shift+Left/Right* works for me (by default). Are there other commands bound to *Ctrl+Shift+Left* than *Select Previous Word*? Press *Ctrl+Shift+L* to see a list of current active keys.

Comment: I reset the bindings to default. It seems none of the bindings are working.

Comment: In the preferences dialog what commands are displayed when searching for "Ctrl+Shift+Left"? In a text editor which key is bound to the command *Select Previous Word* (use *Ctrl+Shift+L* in a text editor to find it out)?

Comment: Everything looked fine. I created a new project (luckily I hadn't written anything in this project) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It could also have been that the checkbox "*Always show Welcome at start up*" in the Eclipse IDE's Welcome Tab was checked.

If that's the case, there is a bug in Eclipse that prevents the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> from working.

["Ctrl+Shift+Right/Left" doesn't select a word in Eclipse as it ought to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460078/ctrlshiftright-left-doesnt-select-a-word-in-eclipse-as-it-ought-to-do)

Answer (score 0):

It was a Maven project that was imported and had been created in a previous version of *Eclipse*. When creating a new project the problem disappeared. No idea why.