# "Ctrl+Shift+Right/Left" doesn't select a word in Eclipse as it ought to do

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Eclipse 2019-12 (Java) on Windows 10 Pro and **I cannot get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd> to select a word** as it ought to do. When I press the keys nothing at all happens.

The Preferences seems to be just fine.

[image]

Comment: *in which editor* in Eclipse does it not work right?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in the text editor (maybe it is an issue of the specific editor you are using)? Does Ctrl+3 and entering `Select Next Word` work (maybe the shortcut is catched by Windows or by a tool, not by Eclipse)? Is _Select Next Word_ shown in the Ctrl+Shift+L list?

Comment: Right-click a file and choose _Open With > Other..._ to get a list of all editors (if you really want to know that). I cannot reproduce this issue in Eclipse 2019-12 in the Java editor. So, please answer my question of my last comment to find out why you have this issue. It is very likely the shortcut is caught by a Windows tool, since this is a [common shortcut of Windows display driver tools](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/ctrlshiftarrow-shortcut-doesnt-seem-to-work/8fb025fb-3c79-4ade-90d7-87e08fef5ff1).

Comment: You're saying it does not work "as it is supposed to". You haven't said what it's actually doing.  Describe exactly what you have when you press the key sequence, and what the result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug in the Eclipse IDE's Welcome Tab.

If the checkbox "*Always show Welcome at start up*" (in the Eclipse IDE's Welcome Tab) is checked,
then the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> doesn't work.

[image: Welcome Screen - Always show Welcome at start up]

The solution:
**Uncheck the checkbox** "*Always show Welcome at start up*" and **restart Eclipse**.